# Are there any problems with implementing deleted usernames this way?

Tags: design, implementations

I have a requirement to implement usernames for an application for login purposes. The requirement specifies that the registry associated with the user/username in the database must not be deleted. The requirement specifies that the username once marked "deleted", must be available for reuse.

So, currently, the implementation changes a flag boolean "deleted" to true, so when login is triggered, the query verifies that the username exist and the boolean "deleted" is false.

Are there any problems with implementing deleted usernames this way? Are there other solutions that avoid these problems?

Comment: Reusable by the same person or by a different person?

Comment: What do you mean by a "good practice?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354

Comment: There's lots of help [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=soft%20deletion).  Can you do a bit more research, and then ask us a more specific question?

Comment: Are you capturing the user's email address?  If you use this as your key, then you can delete by removing the user id itself.  That's a lot cleaner than a "deleted" flag in my opinion and makes "reuse" of usernames trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't implement deleting usernames in this fashion by using a `boolean` flag. You are correct that there are problems with implementing it this way; specifically, what happens when another user registers that username? Do you simply set the deleted flag back to true? What happens if *that* user then deletes the account? Your historical record has vanished!

Note that you have two requirements:

- Provide username functionality for your application
- Provide a historical record for username additions and deletions

It is not necessary to attempt to solve both problems in the same table! What you should do instead is **archive** the registration upon deletion, instead of having a boolean flag. This way you:

- Don't clutter the active username table with lots of irrelevant data
- Have a good system for when the same username is deleted over and over again (just have multiple entries in the archive table)

This solution should solve both of your implementation concerns.

Comment: How do you reinstate the user name without breaking the ID?  You still need the boolean flag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No you don't, because you don't necessarily want to give a new registration the same ID as the previous user. This could result in a lot of database cleanup. The historical record could restore the id and recreate it that way

Comment: It's hard to imagine why you would ever need a new ID, unless it is not the original user, in which case it is a brand new account anyway.  In practice, user names should be unique amongst the "live" records.  It shouldn't be possible to restore a user name that is already in use by someone else.

Comment: Not only do they need to know who are the active users now, but some auditor is going to want to know "Who were the active users last year?" or some other time.

Comment: By archive you mean, moving the data to another table, Asuming that al data moved can be used to audit in the archive table?

Comment: @nicoLinjava Another table, yes. And in another table you can have historical fields that might not make sense in the username table (like account deletion reason)